# Cannot (Unable to) shutdown, reboot or logout in KDE Plasma (version 5.8.8)

Tags: kde, plasma

When pressing "Reboot" the following is written to `~/.xsession-errors` file:

```
Shutdown called with confirm  -1  type  1  and mode  -1
```

But it does not reboot.

Answer (score 4):

File `~/.config/ksmserverrc` might be causing an issue.

1. Remove it:

   ```
   rm ~/.config/ksmserverrc
   ```
2. Logout, since you can't do it (because it's your problem) do this:

   ```
   killall Xorg
   ```
3. Login to Plasma desktop again and reboot should work for you.

Not yet clear what the problem could be with `ksmserverrc` file (TODO).

Solution inspired by [this forum thread](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/61623-How-I-got-this-fixed-gt-KDE-cannot-logout-shutdown-reboot-etc).

Comment: Can confirm this worked on Debian Stretch (9.5). When I click Reboot after following these steps I get the dark grey overlay with the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The file that I had to delete was ~/.kde/share/config/ksmserverrc
The path in some threads discussing this is "~/.config/ksmserverrc" and that is not correct.

Comment: Which version of KDE?

Comment: That must be an outdated KDE. Looking at the version distributed with Debian Stretch (9.5) the path `~/.config/ksmserverrc` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have You installed chrome-remote-desktop? if yes then that is the one creating an issue for u.

try command `killall chrome-remote-desktop-host`
then do shutdown if works you can create a autostart script.